# How to trigger a Cell that contains a Date and change another Cell Value if the Date expired

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel-Sheet that contains a column with different Dates.
Another Column contains Values like "Red,Yellow and Blue". Regarding to the Date the String "Red,Yellow or Blue" should be set.
A VBA Code like this with a loop is easy but how can i write the Code that changes the String Value automatically when the Date Expire.
Date is Expired when its bigger than NOW().

Which function should be used to track the Excel sheet as long as a value has been changed?

Comment: `=IF(A1>NOW(),"Red","Green")`?

Comment: I don't want it to be seen for others that might use the Excel sheet so i thought of a VBA-Code ( Private sub)

Comment: it also didnt change the Colour if someone changed the Date to an expired one!